Visual Studio Installer - Automatically Chooses Non-Existing Drive
The Visual Studio Code installer always chooses the E:/ drive although there is none and I have tried and failed fixing it with the Command Prompt solution
The Command Prompt solution of running it with a already set path from File Explorer and expected it to work but it didn't

Just to be clear, the installer you're using is the Windows User Installer (presumably x64, not sure if Arm64 would make a difference), correct?
https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads
I believe it might be using one of the special folders. If you ever pulled any OS level trickery with your paths, I'd check that out first.
